# Passing value from app.config file to component

Tags: angular

I have a function in my app.config file which reads the current environment using window.location.hostname. I need this value in another component. How do I pass it to this component?

My app.config file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { IAppConfig } from "./app-config.model";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
  currentUrl: string;
  currentEnv: string;

    private static _settings: IAppConfig;

    get settings(): IAppConfig {
        return AppConfig._settings;
    }

    static set settings(value: IAppConfig) {
        AppConfig._settings = value;
    }
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {


  }


    load() {
      this.configEnv()
      console.log(this.currentEnv)
      console.log(this.currentUrl)
      const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${this.currentEnv}.json`;
      console.log(`Loading file ${jsonFile}`)
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response : IAppConfig) => {
               AppConfig.settings = <IAppConfig>response;
               resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
               reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
               console.log(jsonFile);


            });
        });
    }

    configEnv() {
      this.currentUrl = window.location.hostname;
      switch (true) {
        case this.currentUrl.includes('local'):
          this.currentEnv = 'local'
          break;
        case this.currentUrl.includes('dev'):
          this.currentEnv = 'dev'
          break;
        case this.currentUrl.includes('uat'):
          this.currentEnv = 'uat'
          break;
        case this.currentUrl == 'http://xxxxxx':
          this.currentEnv = ('prod')
          break;
        default:
           console.log ('environment not found, redirecting to dev env');
           this.currentEnv ='dev'
              }
    }


}
```

I need to pass the currentEnv value in my component. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you learned the use of [services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) in Angular ? Try the angular tutorial. You will learn all the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service modify this section, `providedIn: 'root'` is important:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfig {
  // all your code
}
```

Then in your components reference it like this:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(
        public config: AppConfig // You can name it whatever you want as long as the type matches
    ) { }
    someThing() {
        this.config.currentUrl;
    }
}
```

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#services